# TIMESTAMP/DATETIME : Count the Number of Rows Grouping By Month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with a dataset that has data about taxi trips.

These are the jsons where i got the data to create the tables:

1. [2009](https://s3.amazonaws.com/data-sprints-eng-test/data-sample_data-nyctaxi-trips-2009-json.json)
2. [2010](https://s3.amazonaws.com/data-sprints-eng-test/data-sample_data-nyctaxi-trips-2010-json.json)
3. [2011](https://s3.amazonaws.com/data-sprints-eng-test/data-sample_data-nyctaxi-trips-2011-json.json)
4. [2012](https://s3.amazonaws.com/data-sprints-eng-test/data-sample_data-nyctaxi-trips-2012-json.json)

These are also avaliable on this [google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yN4HTNwNo5Yd5Y_KP0xSr6wM58c6DuVE)

You can ignore the vendor lookup dataset, since it is only a lookup for the different names same data have.

My intentions are to produce a result like this:

```
| Line  | frequency     | month     | year  |
|------ |-----------    |-------    |------ |
| 1     |    20         | 1         | 2009  |
| 2     |    35         | 2         | 2009  |
| 3     |    90         | 3         | 2009  |
| 4     |    24         | 4         | 2009  |
| 5     |    12         | 5         | 2009  |
```

The Queries i've tried look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(payment_type) as frequency,
       month,
       year
FROM
(
SELECT NYCTaxiTrips.pickup_datetime as pickup_datetime,
       paymentlookup.string_field_0 as payment_type , 
       EXTRACT( MONTH FROM NYCTaxiTrips.pickup_datetime) as month,
       EXTRACT( YEAR FROM NYCTaxiTrips.pickup_datetime) as year
FROM `datasprintsteste.datasets.PaymentLookup` as paymentlookup
INNER JOIN  
(
SELECT payment_type, pickup_datetime FROM `datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2009` 
UNION ALL
SELECT payment_type, pickup_datetime FROM `datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2010` 
UNION ALL
SELECT payment_type, pickup_datetime FROM `datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2011` 
UNION ALL
SELECT payment_type, pickup_datetime FROM `datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2012` 
) AS NYCTaxiTrips
ON paymentlookup.string_field_0 = NYCTaxiTrips.payment_type
)
WHERE payment_type = 'Cash'
GROUP BY month, year
```

But this is the result they gave:

```
| Line  | frequency     | month     | year  |
|------ |-----------    |-------    |------ |
| 1     |  1389172      | 1         | 2009  |
```

I've tried to not group by year, but it yelds an error, I am pretty sure it is syntax.

How would I do a query like the one I want?

Comment: Looking at your example data I can only find data from Jan (month = 1). Can you please provide a much smaller data sample, You current sample is over 300M!!! for 1 file,  with a variety of months and show your SQL is not working

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that too. It seems this data sample has only the first month of each year, but the documentation doesn't even mention that.

Comment: Changing the data to include a lesser amount of rows, without changing the months distribution would be way above my skill level!!
My problem here is that the query i tried outputed just one year, 2009, wich i found very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of your SQL code with smaller data sample for you to play and test

```
WITH `datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2009` AS (
SELECT 'cach' AS payment_type, TIMESTAMP('2009-01-01 02:18:18.000') as pickup_datetime UNION ALL
SELECT 'cach' AS payment_type, TIMESTAMP('2009-02-01 02:18:18.000') as pickup_datetime
), 
`datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2010` AS (
SELECT 'cach' AS payment_type, TIMESTAMP('2010-03-01 02:18:18.000') as pickup_datetime UNION ALL
SELECT 'cach' AS payment_type, TIMESTAMP('2010-04-01 02:18:18.000') as pickup_datetime
), 
`datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2011` AS (
SELECT 'cach' AS payment_type, TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01 02:18:18.000') as pickup_datetime UNION ALL
SELECT 'cach' AS payment_type, TIMESTAMP('2011-01-01 02:18:18.000') as pickup_datetime
),
`datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2012` AS (
SELECT 'cach' AS payment_type, TIMESTAMP('2012-05-01 02:18:18.000') as pickup_datetime UNION ALL
SELECT 'cach' AS payment_type, TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01 02:18:18.000') as pickup_datetime
),
`all` AS (
SELECT * FROM `datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2009` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2010` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2011` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `datasprintsteste.datasets.NYCTaxiTrips2012` 
)

SELECT COUNT(payment_type) as frequency,
       EXTRACT( MONTH FROM pickup_datetime) as month,
       EXTRACT( YEAR FROM pickup_datetime) as year
FROM `all`
GROUP BY month, year
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
```

This produces the desired result with a breakdown per months (I put data not only for the month of Jan in my data sample)

[image]